# How to set filepath in Java ( VPS server Ubuntu)

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-12.04, vps

I have recently developed a web application using Java. everything works fine when offline. When i uploaded my web application to a VPS server linux ubuntu it is not working properly like offline it does.

The problem is, I set a file path in local like `c:project/application/report.pdf` its worked fine. But i dont know how to set path in the server. I even tried `http://101.102.20.203:8080/var/usr/report.pdf`.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use a relative path, if possible. It would help your question get some attention if you post the function or at least some lines showing how you are handling the file in your application, so that someone can help you use the relative path.